# White gap above Jquery mobile footer

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

So I'm building a web application using Jquery Mobile and Phonegap. The app was working fine until I removed some input fields and drop down menus which became obsolete.

The problem now is that when I click on the last input field of the page & the ios keyboard activates, the footer bar is no longer fixed and there is a white gap between the footer bar and the ios keypad. When the keypad hides again I see the full page but the white gap is above the footer.

This doesn't seem to be a problem on the Android platform so I'm wondering if it is a CSS issue. Help is most certainly welcome. Here's the page code in question...

```
<div data-role="page"  data-theme="f" id="">
        <div data-role="header" class="ui-state-persist">
            <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <h1>text</h1>
            <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="no text"></a>
        </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <label for="">Text</label>
                <input type="text" name="text" id="" value="" class="input-field required"/>
                <label for="">Text</label>
                <input type="text" name="" id="" value="" class="input-field required"/>
                <label for="">Text</label>
                <input type="text" name="" id="" value="" class="input-field required"/>
                <label for="">Text</label>
                <input type="" name="" id="" value="" class="input-field required"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" class="ui-state-persist"  style="min-height:42px;">
                <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="left" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px">Done</a>
                <a href="#main_menu" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="notext" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 5px"></a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code (using jQuery Mobile version 1.2.0):

```
<div data-role="page"  data-theme="f" id="quickquote_insured">

    <div data-role="header" class="ui-state-persist">
        <a href="#quickquote_menu" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>Contact Details</h1>
        <a href="#quickquote_driver_profile" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <label for="quickquote-insured_initials">Initials:</label>
        <input type="text" name="quickquote-insured_initials" id="quickquote-insured_initials" value="" class="input-field required"/>
        <label for="quickquote-insured_surname">Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="quickquote-insured_surname" id="quickquote-insured_surname" value="" class="input-field required"/>
        <label for="quickquote-insured_phone_number">Mobile number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="quickquote-insured_phone_number" id="quickquote-insured_phone_number" value="" class="input-field required"/>
        <label for="quickquote-insured_email_address">e-Mail address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="quickquote-insured_email_address" id="quickquote-insured_email_address" value="" class="input-field required"/>

        <br>

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-state-persist"  style="min-height:42px;">
        <a href="#quickquote_menu" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="left" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px">Done</a>
        <a href="#main_menu" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="notext" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 5px"></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

I know it may look simple, but I just added a `<br>` just under your email input field.

I think the problem is that, since your footer is "static", you need to "fill" your page.

For example, if you have few fields on your page and if you don't "fill" your page, you'll get the following result:

[image: 1]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Littm. I implemented your suggestion and it did decrease the amount of white space. It also pushed the footer bar into the ios keypad which is not ideal either We're using JQM 1.1.0 - do you think this is partly the problem? Any other suggestions? Help is much appreciated :-)

Comment: I think it's better to use the latest version of jQuery Mobile (1.2.0 at the moment), since it is more stable (several bugs were corrected).